# SAPUI5 list is not auto-growing

Tags: sapui5

I have a *UI5 List* which has the following attributes

```
growing="true"
growingTreshold="50"
growingScrollToLoad="true"
```

This list is inside a fragment which I include into my view. It used to work pretty well with my old project but unfortunatly since I refactored everything and included SAPUI5 Routing it doesn´t work anymore. 
Now if I scroll down it shows me a [More] list item which shows the next 50 entries. Funny about that is, that I get an console error when I click on more stating

> Uncaught Error: The segment {id} is required.

I guess this means the inhability of the list to auto-grow is somehow related to my new routing. The components I use look like this

```js
{
    pattern : "",
    name : navigation.Constants.MyEvents,
    view : navigation.Constants.MyEvents,
    viewId : navigation.Constants.MyEvents,
    targetAggregation : "pages",
    targetControl : "idAppControl",
    subroutes : [
        {
            pattern : "{id}",
            name : navigation.Constants.EventDetailFragment,
            view : navigation.Constants.EventDetailFragment
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone now how to solve this problem? So far I couldn´t find anything related to my problem.

Comment: Hello Felix, there are too many context factors that could break you code. I suggest to create a simple application in jsfiddle. You could use this bootstrap example: http://jsfiddle.net/urp0pfqq/1/

Comment: The error 'The segment {id} is required' is raised by the routing. It seems that you´re routing to a page without handing over the `id` as a parameter which is required according to your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

When navigating to the new page in your routing pass in the `{id}` parameter. i.e

```js
this.getRouter().navTo("yourNewPage", {
    from: currentView,
    id: passedinHere
}, false);
```

Not having that is whats tripping up your code.